# How to check in protractor is mat-select disable, if there is no "disabled" in snippet?

Tags: protractor

I work with tables in page objects and want to avoid getAttribute(mat-select-disabled), just isEnabled(), as other elements such as inputs and checkboxes, which have "disabled"

```
<mat-select class="mat-select mat-select-disabled formcontrolname="xxx" role="listbox" aria-disabled="true"></mat-select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not built on method for this and you can not avoid the `getAttribute` method because your element does not have the `disabled` attribute, just only has a class name.

But you can always create your own, something like this:

```
// async/await

async function isElementDisabled(elem) { @elem <ElementFinder>
  const classNames = await elem.getAttribute('class');

  return classNames.includes('mat-select-disabled');
}

// Promise based

function isElementDisabled(elem) { // @elem <ElementFinder>
  return elem.getAttribute('class').then(classNames => classNames.includes('mat-select-disabled'));
}
```

Comment: Would you be so kind, and help me with build expectation with this function?
expect(EC.or((table[i].selector.isEnabled().toBe(false)), isElementDisabled(table[i].selector))); 
returns with: 
Failed: table[i].selector.isEnabled(...).toBe is not a function. I want to check, if the table[i].selector element has disabled attribute, or contains mat-select-disabled in a class.

Comment: Hey @CzescTuSlawomr.
Sure, `expect(!(await elm.isEnabled()) || await isElementDisabled(elm)).toBe(true);`